# Access a template variable from another template (or theme hook)

Tags: theming, 8, hooks, paragraphs

I have two templates (and two corresponding preprocess hooks), one rendering a Paragraph, one rendering items from this paragraph.

How to access a variable available in the parent paragraph template (or preprocess Hook) from the items rendering template (or item preprocess hook) ?

paragraph--paragraph-row.html.twig

```
{{ content.MyVARIABLE }}  //it works
```

field--paragraph--paragraph-row2.html.twig

```
<div class="row">
  {% for item in items %}
     <div class="col-sm-{{ 12 // parent.MyVARIABLE  }}">
         {{ item }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

THANKS !

David

Comment: `parent.` is a bit confusing here, for a field the parent is the entity the field is placed in, possible a paragraph for nested paragraphs, but can be any entity. Or do you mean the paragraphs stored in the field, more like children then?

Comment: "parent" means I want to access the paragraph the field is nested in.

Answer (score 2):

You can't access easily variables from other templates. But you can use the entity objects to access field values.

For a nested paragraph you find the parent paragraph in `element['#object']`:

*field--paragraph.html.twig*

```
{{ element['#object'].field_my_field.value }}
```

Comment: This is a really important information. Where can it be found in the documentation?